# Calling non static method in Activity from another Activity

Tags: android

I want to call non static method in my Activity A from Activity B 
like

```
class A extend Activity(){ public void c(){}}
class B extend Activity(){ A.C(); }
```

How I could do this in android Activity help me.

```
public class Voice extends Activity {

TextView resultTEXT ;
MediaPlayer mp;
ImageView view;


private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;

int page;

// SPP UUID service
private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// String for MAC address
private static String address;
private static String status;
BluetoothDevice device;



private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice);
    //get the stored mac address of the device
    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("BtAddress", MODE_PRIVATE);
    address = (shared.getString("btAddress", ""));
    status = (shared.getString("connect", ""));
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    //create device and set the MAC address
    device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    checkBTState();

    if(status=="true")
    {
        new CountDownTimer(1000, 10000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Voice.this, R.drawable.onload);
                mp.setLooping(false);
                mp.start();
            }

        }.start();

    }

    view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


        Handler handler = new Handler();

        int numberOfTaps = 0;
        long lastTapTimeMs = 0;
        long touchDownMs = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touchDownMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

                    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - touchDownMs) > ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()) {
                        //it was not a tap

                        numberOfTaps = 0;
                        lastTapTimeMs = 0;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (numberOfTaps > 0
                            && (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTapTimeMs) < ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout()) {
                        numberOfTaps += 1;
                    } else {
                        numberOfTaps = 1;
                    }

                    lastTapTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if (numberOfTaps == 2) {
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //handle double tap
                                Toast.makeText(Voice.this, "Help", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Voice.this, R.drawable.help);
                                mp.setLooping(false);
                                mp.start();
                            }
                        }, ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout());
                    }
                    else if(numberOfTaps== 1)
                    {
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(Voice.this, "proceed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent=new Intent(Voice.this,ChangeSpeed.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }, ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout());

                    }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}



public  void  onActivityResult(int request_result, int result_code, Intent i)
{

    super.onActivityResult(result_code, result_code, i);

    switch (result_code)
    {

        case 100: if(result_code == RESULT_OK && i != null)
        {
            ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            resultTEXT.setText(result.get(0));


        }
            break;


    }

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    try
    {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
    try
    {
        btSocket.connect();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e2)
        {
            Log.e("",""+e2);
        }
    }
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
    //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
    mConnectedThread.write("x");
}
private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

    return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);

}
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    try
    {
        // Bluetooth sockets close when leaving activity
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2)
    {
        Log.e("",""+e2);
    }
}
/*
//Checks that the Android device Bluetooth is available  turned on if off automatically
*/

private void checkBTState()
{

    if(btAdapter==null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else
    {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    //  private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    //creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket)
    {
        // InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try
        {
            //Create I/O streams for connection
            // tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }

        //mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    //write method
    public void write(String input)
    {
        byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();
        //converts entered String into bytes
        try
        {

            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            //if you cannot write, close the application
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

        }
    }

}
/*
method to on the Fan
 */
public  void functionFanOn()
{

    mConnectedThread.write("1");
    // Send "1" via Bluetooth
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on Fan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("", "On");
}
```

functionFanOn() is the method that I want to call in B

Comment: why do you want that? 
what is the purpose of the method?

Comment: You can't. Can you specify the purpose?

Comment: Well,I want connect to bluetooth  and I have method in class A which send signals to Arduino At that class I create the connection also so in class B  when user click button I want to send signal to Arduino calling that method in class A

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the structure of your code. The function in Activity **A**, which establishes a connection to the Arduino, should be move in another class. Lets say an **Utils** class.

Answer (score 1):

1. Refactoring your common code to an new class, so that you can manager it by single instance
2. This lib [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) may solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Another Way is Create Seprate class and use all method of seprate class

```
class Utils
{
    public void c(Context context)
    {
        //put your code
        }
}
```

And Activity class Like this

```
class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        //method calling
        Utils utils=new utils();
        utils.c(MyActivity.this);
    }


}
```

Answer (score -3):

Please read my sample code

Is this one activity class like this and contain c(); method

```
class A extend Activity
{ 
    public void c()
    {

    }
}
```

And This is your Second activity class

```
class B extend Activity
{ 
    A a=new A();

    a.c();
}
```

i hope this help you

Comment: Although, this is technically true (a.k.a. you can do that), this is a VERY VERY bad approach!

Comment: Why do you need it in a separate activity?

Comment: NEVER create an `Activity` in Android this way. It does not correctly initialise it and will cause you a lot more issues than it will fix

Comment: ok tell me what kind of issue occur when create activity class object??